# Conflicting names of IBOutlet and IBAction?

Tags: swift, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

I have the following references from a UICollectionViewCell class to a button in the cell on the storyboard. Clicking the button does not trigger 'setFavorite'.

```
class StationCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var favorite: UIButton!

    @IBAction func setFavorite(sender: AnyObject) {
       println("Button clicked")
    }
}
```

But when I change the name of the  action-function or the outlet-variable to something else (for instance to 'setAsFavorite' or 'favoriteButton') it works.

Is there some 'magic' done by xCode of Swift that prevents me to have both an outlet named 'favorite' and an action named 'setFavorite'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic belongs to NSObject. A property called `favourite` has two accessor methods: `favourite`, which returns the property value, and `setFavourite:`, which sets the value. With the code above you're breaking this assumption, which is why changing the method name works.